# gem5OpJni in GEM5 -- Is it supported for x86 or do I have to build it my own?

Tags: gem5

Is m5Op and its JNI interface available to all Architectures ?

Being at : ~/gem5/util

grep -Ril "gem5OpJni" .

Only found the following two files:

./m5/Makefile.aarch64

./m5/Makefile.arm

Both of which are related to ARM.